# How to get unique values for all variables in a dataset

Tags: stata, unique-values

I'm using Stata. I have a dataset with approximately 1800 observations and 1050 variables. Most of them are categorical variables with a few categories. It looks something like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------
| id | fh_1 | fh_1a | fh_2 | fh_2a | fh_3 | fh_3a |...
------------------------------------------------------
|1111| 1    |closed | 2    | 4     | 1    | open  |...
------------------------------------------------------
|1112| 2    | open  | 1    | 2     | 3    | closed|...
------------------------------------------------------
.
.
.
```

I need to export to an Excel sheet the list of all variables in this dataset with all unique values for each variable. It should look something like this:

```
--------------------------
|variable | unique_values|
--------------------------
| fh      | 1 2 3 4 5    |
--------------------------
|fh_1a    | closed open  |
--------------------------
.
.
.
```

I think I need a loop with the command `levelsof` but I'm not sure how to build it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach v of var * { 
    levelsof `v' 
}
```

would be a start, but I haven't directly addressed how to make that output Excel-friendly.

One possibility is to put all the output in string variables given that the number of observations exceeds the number of variables.

```
gen varname = "" 
gen levels = "" 
local i = 1 
foreach v of var * { 
    levelsof `v' 
    replace varname = "`v'" in `i' 
    replace levels = `"`r(levels)'"' in `i' 
    local ++i 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to solve it. You might run in to issues if you have strings variable where some observations have values that are strings composed of more than one word. Then there is no way to tell if it was one observation with both words or two observations with one word each.

The values are sorted alphabetically, so you might be able to figure out anyway, but it could be ambivalent.

```
sysuse auto,clear

* Get a list of all vars apart from whatever var we do not want to include
ds make, not
local all_vars_but_id `r(varlist)'
* Get the number of vars, represents the number of rows in the dataset to be exported
local num_vars : word count `all_vars_but_id'

* Get the values for each var and store in local with same name as var
foreach var of local all_vars_but_id {
    levelsof `var'
    local `var' `r(levels)'
}

*Preserve the original data
preserve

    * Remove the data and set up the data set to be exported
    clear 
    set obs `num_vars'
    gen var    = ""
    gen values = ""

    * Copy the value of the locals created abobe to one row per variable
    local counter 1
    foreach var of local all_vars_but_id {
        replace var = "`var'"      if _n == `counter'
        replace values = "``var''" if _n == `counter'
        local counter = `counter' + 1
    }
    
    * Export to Excel
    export excel using "C:\path/to/file/unique_values.xls"
  
*Restore the original data
restore
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `levelsof`

```
input id str6(var1 var2 var3)
1 "open" "2" "3"
2 "closed" "1" "2"
3 "open" "1" "1"
end

reshape long var, i(id)

rename var values
rename _j var

gen unique_values = ""

forvalues i = 1/3 {
    levelsof values if var == `i'
    replace unique_values = r(levels) if var == `i'
}

replace unique_values = subinstr(unique_values,"`","",.)
replace unique_values = subinstr(unique_values,`"""',"",.)
replace unique_values = subinstr(unique_values,"'","",.)

contract var unique_values
drop _freq

list, noobs
```